# Can someone help plz asap

Tags: jeep, serpentine-belt, cherokee

What belt size I need for a 2004 Jeep Cherokee 4.o engine if I’m trying to by pass the a/c pulley.The a/c compressor is old and keep kicking the belt off so now my car won’t crank at all.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is this a "Cherokee" or a "Grand Cherokee" ... what I'm seeing is, they didn't make a Cherokee in 2004, for the States, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't get a direct answer you could use a length of taut string (blue on the drawing) to trace the route bypassing the A/C compressor.

At suitable locations where the belt and string follow the same route, mark the belt and string.

Remove the belt and measure the long section between the marks and add on the length of the string between its marks.

Even if the picture isn't your engine, you should be able to do the same process.

[image]

I got this picture from [here](https://jeepspecs.com/wj-generation/wj-jeep-parts-equipment/serpentine-belts/)

Comment: Could you also include *how* they can then use this to find a new belt of the right length? I've been meaning to do a write-up of this so it could be used for ALL questions of this sort.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 What sort of things were you thinking about?  Feel free to add anything you want.

Comment: Each ribbed belt is identified by the number of ribs and the length in cm. Most brands put this into the part number. If you count the ribs and know the length you need, you can translate this into most any belt.